# Differential forms and wedge product exercise.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning, multilinear-algebra

> Show that $$\omega \wedge v(\left <a_1,a_2,a_3 \right>,\left <b_1,b_2,b_3 \right>) = c_1 dx\wedge dy + c_2 dx\wedge dz + c_3 dy \wedge dz.$$

I wasn't given the form of $\omega$ or $v$. Furthermore, to my knowledge we can only compute the wedge product of a vector right? How come the RHS doesn't evaluate a vector? For instance,  shouldn't we get $c_1 dx\wedge dy (vector)$ on the RHS? I am using bachman's book (the book is free on arvix).

So I assume we can let $\omega(a_1,a_2,a_3) = \omega_1a_1 + \omega_2 a_2 + \omega_3 a_3$ and similar definition for $v.$ Should I just group all the $\omega_ia_i, \omega_ib_i, v_ia_i,v_ib_i$ terms together and call that the mixed constants in $a_ib_i$ as $c_i$?

The book can be found here http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306194 which is made free and the question is found on page 25 in the pdf.

Comment: What is the relationship between the $c_i$'s and the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s? What you have on the right hand side seems like a general two form on $\Bbb R^3$. Where can I find the exercise?

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ, that's what I am wondering too. Everything outside the grey box is a hypothesis.

Comment: Please go to page 25 of the book

Comment: Those are not arbitrary 2-forms. Take their definition in the previous page. Also, note that notation in that notes is a bit different from usual and $dx$ might indicate the first component of a vector.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, are you referring to $<\omega >  = <a,b,c>$? because that one makes less sense to me in this problem here.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, Unless you claim that this would imply $\omega (\left< a_1, a_2, a_3 \right >) = a_1dx + a_2dy + a_3dz$, then maybe. But I am not seeing the relationship right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're given that $\omega,\nu \in \Omega^1( \mathbb{R}^3) $, so we can treat these guys as vectors that take the form ( with basis $dx,dy,dz$ and $a,b,c, s,t,u \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$ \omega = a dx + b dy + c dz \quad \& \quad \nu = s dx + t dy + u dz $$

The exercise says to compute $ \omega \wedge \nu$, so lets do that

\begin{align*}
 \omega \wedge \nu =& ( a dx + b dy + c dz ) \wedge (s dx + t dy + u dz) \\
=& a t \,  dx \wedge dy + b s  \, dy \wedge dx + au  \, dx \wedge dz + c s \, dz \wedge dx + \ldots \\
= & (at - bs ) dx \wedge dy + (au - cs) dx \wedge dz + (bu-tc) dy \wedge dz \\
=& c_1 dx \wedge dy + c_2 dx \wedge dz + c_3 dy \wedge dz
\end{align*}

We used the fact that $dx \wedge dx = 0$.Also! In general the the wedge product acts on differential forms not just vectors but in this case we can identify a 3-vector on the RHS by using the basis $dx\wedge dy, dy \wedge dz, dz \wedge dx$

Comment: Something doesn't make sense to me here. Why is the notation $\omega \wedge v = \omega \wedge v (\left <a_1,a_2,a_3 \right>,\left <b_1,b_2,b_3 \right>) $

Comment: This answer seems to also contradict exercise 2.12 in the book.

Comment: Okay I found out the problem. Apparently I was using an outdated version of the book.